# mina deploy successful however no updates to the site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, mina

I've searched everywhere but can't seem to find an answer.  I have setup mina and after fixing some errors I am able to deploy with mina with no errors.  However, no changes to the site.  Site is on DO running Ubuntu, Nginx, Unicorn.

```
require 'mina/bundler'
require 'mina/rails'
require 'mina/git'
require 'mina/rbenv'

set :rails_evn, 'production'
set :domain, 'ip-address'
set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/app_name/'
set :repository, 'https://github.com/...'
set :branch, 'master'
set :user, 'deploy'
set :ssh_options, '-A'
set :forward_agent, true
set :port, '22'
set :unicorn_pid, "#{deploy_to}/shared/pids/unicorn.pid"
set :term_mode, nil


set :shared_paths, ['config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml', 'log']


task :environment do
  queue %{echo "-----> Loading environment"
#{echo_cmd %[source ~/.bashrc]}
}

  invoke :'rbenv:load'

end


task :setup => :environment do
  queue! %[mkdir -p "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/log"]
  queue! %[chmod g+rx,u+rwx "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/log"]

  queue! %[mkdir -p "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config"]
  queue! %[chmod g+rx,u+rwx "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config"]

  queue! %[touch "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"]
  queue! %[touch "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config/secrets.yml"]
  queue  %[echo "-----> Be sure to edit '#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config/database.yml' and 'secrets.yml'."]

  queue %[
    repo_host=`echo $repo | sed -e 's/.*@//g' -e 's/:.*//g'` &&
    repo_port=`echo $repo | grep -o ':[0-9]*' | sed -e 's/://g'` &&
    if [ -z "${repo_port}" ]; then repo_port=22; fi &&
    ssh-keyscan -p $repo_port -H $repo_host >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  ]
end

desc "Deploys the current version to the server."
task :deploy => :environment do
  to :before_hook do
    # Put things to run locally before ssh
  end
  deploy do
    invoke :'git:clone'
    invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths'
    invoke :'bundle:install'
    invoke :'rails:db_migrate'
    invoke :'rails:assets_precompile'

    to :launch do
      queue "mkdir -p #{deploy_to}/#{current_path}/tmp/"
      queue "touch #{deploy_to}/#{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
      invoke :'deploy:cleanup'
    end
  end
end
```

The following is from 'mina deploy -v':

```
mina deploy -v
deploy@domain password:
-----> Loading environment
$ source ~/.bashrc
-----> Loading rbenv
$ export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv"
$ export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
$ eval "$(rbenv init -)"
-----> Creating a temporary build path
$ touch "deploy.lock"
$ mkdir -p "$build_path"
$ cd "$build_path"
-----> Fetching new git commits
$ (cd "/home/deploy/app_name//scm" && git fetch "https://github.com/../.git" "master:master" --force)
Username for 'https://github.com':
Password for 'https://@github.com':
remote: Counting objects: 4, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 3), reused 4 (delta 3), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.
From https://github.com/user/app_name
   99242a0..7169a04  master     -> master
-----> Using git branch 'master'
$ git clone "/home/deploy/app_name//scm" . --recursive --branch "master"
Cloning into '.'...
done.
-----> Using this git commit

$ git rev-parse HEAD > .mina_git_revision
$ git --no-pager log --format='%aN (%h):%n> %s' -n 1
Tabish (7169a04):
> changes to deploy.rb
$ rm -rf .git

-----> Symlinking shared paths
$ mkdir -p "./config"
$ mkdir -p "."
$ rm -rf "./config/database.yml"
$ ln -s "/home/deploy/app_name//shared/config/database.yml" "./config/database.yml"
$ rm -rf "./config/secrets.yml"
$ ln -s "/home/deploy/app_name//shared/config/secrets.yml" "./config/secrets.yml"
$ rm -rf "./log"
$ ln -s "/home/deploy/app_name//shared/log" "./log"
-----> Installing gem dependencies using Bundler
$ mkdir -p "/home/deploy/app_name//shared/bundle"
$ mkdir -p "./vendor"
$ ln -s "/home/deploy/app_name//shared/bundle" "./vendor/bundle"
$ bundle install --without development:test --path "./vendor/bundle" --deployment
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.8.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.2.4
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile 0.6.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.6.2
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
Using loofah 2.0.3
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
Using actionview 4.2.4
Using rack 1.6.4
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.2.4
Using globalid 0.3.6
Using activejob 4.2.4
Using mime-types 2.6.2
Using mail 2.6.3
Using actionmailer 4.2.4
Using activemodel 4.2.4
Using arel 6.0.3
Using activerecord 4.2.4
Using execjs 2.6.0
Using autoprefixer-rails 6.0.3
Using bcrypt 3.1.10
Using sass 3.4.18
Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.5.1
Using climate_control 0.0.3
Using cocaine 0.5.7
Using coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.2.4
Using coffee-rails 4.1.0
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using responders 2.1.0
Using warden 1.2.3
Using devise 3.5.1
Using font-awesome-rails 4.3.0.0
Using multi_json 1.11.2
Using jbuilder 2.3.2
Using jquery-rails 4.0.5
Using kgio 2.9.3
Using mimemagic 0.3.0
Using open4 1.3.4
Using mina 0.3.7
Using paperclip 4.3.1 from git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git (at master)
Using pg 0.18.3
Using bundler 1.10.6
Using sprockets 3.3.5
Using sprockets-rails 2.3.3
Using rails 4.2.4
Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.2
Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.3
Using rails_12factor 0.0.2
Using raindrops 0.14.0
Using rdoc 4.2.0
Using tilt 2.0.1
Using sass-rails 5.0.4
Using sdoc 0.4.1
Using simple_form 3.2.0
Using turbolinks 2.5.3
Using uglifier 2.7.2
Using unicorn 4.9.0
Bundle complete! 21 Gemfile dependencies, 69 gems now installed.
Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
-----> DB migrations unchanged; skipping DB migration
-----> Skipping asset precompilation
$ mkdir -p "/home/deploy/app_name//$build_path/public/assets"
$ cp -R "/home/deploy/app_name//current/public/assets/." "/home/deploy/app_name//$build_path/public/assets"
-----> Deploy finished
-----> Building
-----> Moving build to releases/2
$ mv "$build_path" "$release_path"
$ cd "$release_path"
-----> Build finished
-----> Launching
-----> Updating the current symlink
$ ln -nfs "$release_path" "current"
-----> Launching
$ cd "$release_path"
-----> Cleaning up old releases (keeping 5)
$ cd "/home/deploy/app_name//releases" || exit 15
$ count=`ls -1d [0-9]* | sort -rn | wc -l`
$ remove=$((count > 5 ? count - 5 : 0))
$ ls -1d [0-9]* | sort -rn | tail -n $remove | xargs rm -rf {}
-----> Done. Deployed v2
Connection to domain-name closed.
       Elapsed time: 22.24 seconds
```

I manually restarted unicorn etc however nothing happens.  Thanks!

Edit:  Nginx config:

```
upstream app {
        # Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
        server unix:/home/deploy/app_name/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        root /home/deploy/app_name/public;

        try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

        location @app {
                proxy_pass http://app;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
        client_max_body_size 4G;
        keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this line in your nginx server block

```
root home/deploy/app_name/current/public
```

Comment: I have that line in my nginx sever block

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't have root home/deploy/app_name/current/public but added the 'current' and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

1. (just in case) make sure you restart nginx after changing the config
2. It looks like in the mina logs that there is an extra / after your app name. I'm no Unix guru, but I know sometimes that extra / can cause problems (and other times it doesn't). Remove the extra /  from the end of "deploy_to" at the top of config/deploy.rb:

   set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/app_name'

I just checked an app of mine, which deploys correctly with mina, and it does not have the trailing slash.